# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when running an executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar, executable-jar

I'm currently writing a Chess game with GUI in javaFX and when I run my code inside the IDE ( Eclipse ), it works fine.

However, when I export the file into a runnable jar, most of the time I try to run it, after some time it crashes and generates a log with this header

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007460a390, pid=8064, tid=0x0000000000001b48

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [zip.dll+0xa390]
```

Does anyone know what is the cause of this error? I've tried multiple solutions online and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it is a JVM bug. See [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176548)

Try to use JDK 1.7